# AWS and Quartz for running scheduled tasks

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Grettings everyone,

We are using **AWS** as **PaaS** and we have a couple of microservices deployed there. We got some new requirements to use some sort of cron jobs and schedulers.

***For example we have the following scenarios:***

1. A user can set some rules when an event must happen. For example he wants to remove some oudated documents every Friday or once a week or every 2 days
2. A user can configure creating copies of some objects every day till date A

*I used to use Quartz before and it is the first idea that comes in my mind. I think that we can use it in AWS, cause it has RDS(with PostgreSQL for instance).* 
But I would like to know what sort of other options can I use instead of Quartz(http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) + RDS? May be AWS has something out of the box that can do the same?

What do you think about http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html in my case?

Thank you for your time and advice :)

Comment: I used cron directly, and its simple enough, do you need something more advanced?

Comment: you can schedule lambda function - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, so do you mean that when:
* first user set  some rules for deleting documents, we should launch first AWS lambda
* second user set some other rules(whatever he wants), we should launc anoth AWS lambda function
Is it what you mean? 
Or we can run AWS lambda as Quartz job, poll all objects that must be changed and do some actions with them

Answer (score 0):

Recently(10-Nov-2022) AWS launched a new service called [EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) and I've already added a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74424883/6194097), please have a look. So you don't need to handle anything manually Because [EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) is serverless.