# AWS schedule event using event details

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-sns, schedule, aws-event-bridge

My application is a message processing application and there is an requirment to send a message to a queue based on the date in the input message. It means I can not pre-configured rule to trigger an event, it should be at run-time based on the date in input message.

We are using quartz at the moment to create task and quartz executes these task based on configured time.

I want to avoid Quartz in AWS. How can I design this solution in AWS ?

Comment: what granularity are you looking for? Just dates? Specific hours? Minutes? Seconds? How many of them configured at the same time? You may use event bridge cron based rules, but they are hard limited to 300 I think. If you only need e.g. hourly or daily triggers you can just schedule a lambda based on a 1h / 1d schedule and get the information from a db which messages to send at a given trigger time.

Comment: I'm afraid schedule will be based on date and hours so there will be lot of schedules.

Comment: date + hour is fine. Trigger a lambda hourly and fetch the entries from dynamo. This is a very low cost approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently(10-Nov-2022) AWS launched a new service called [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html). I hope this will fulfill all of your requirements and it's serverless too. So no need to worry about the infrastructure changes.

[image: Comparison chart of EventBridge Scheduler vs EventBridge Rules]

This is a kind of Comparison chart of [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) vs [EventBridge Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) taken from [Introducing Amazon EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) article.

References:-

- [Introducing Amazon EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/)
- [Amazon EventBridge Launches New Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-eventbridge-launches-new-scheduler/)
- [What is Amazon EventBridge Scheduler?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html)
- [How to Easily Trigger an AWS Event at a Specific Time with EventBridge Scheduler](https://beabetterdev.com/2022/11/12/aws-eventbridge-scheduler-tutorial/)

Comment: If you answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501268/eventbridge-scheduler-quota-criteria