# Eventbridge Scheduler quota criteria

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduler, aws-event-bridge

On 10 Nov AWS launched extension of EventBridge as Eventbridge Scheduler. Quota limit of this service is 1 million events per account.

My use-case is to create one time schedule which is possible using Eventbridge Scheduler.

1. Does 1 million events count include events which are already scheduled ?
2. Does Eventbridge Scheduler delete events which have been scheduled or user will have to delete them ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for both questions, users must delete after running

"The maximum number of schedules per account. This quota includes one-time schedules that have completed running. We recommend deleting your one-time schedules after theyve completed running and invoked a target."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/scheduler-quotas.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).